# Past continuous in a subjunctive mood sentence

Tags: grammar, american-english, tenses, past-tense, subjunctive-mood

I was doing some reviewing of the subjunctive mood when I stumbled on this:

> In the that-clause, use a past tense form of the verb even if your
>   sentence has a present or future meaning:
>
> I wish he spoke French.
>
> I wish she was coming with me to Paris.
>
> I wish you hadn’t said that.

http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/advanced-english-grammar-the-subjunctive-mood/

My question is, why would the second example allow a "was" instead of a "were", being this a subjunctive mood example?
Is it because the past continuous requires the auxiliary verb to be conjugated according to the subject?

[*] Sorry if my grammar is not good, it's my first time here and English is not my first language nor my second.
[**] Feel free to correct any other mistake you may find in my redaction.

Answer (score 1):

Because people are lazy and speak sloppy English. The second example should indeed be "were". That article is simply wrong.

"I wish" indicates a mood of possibility, not reality, so the subjunctive *were*is appropriate, whereas *was* indicates a definite past happening.